# What's a good title to a presentations' table of contents?

Tags: business-writing, titles

This is a professional presentation, I'm looking for a good title for the ToC page (some humor allowed).

What I have so far is "What am I going to talk about", which frankly kind of sucks.
Your suggestions?

Comment: chaotic, typically you mark a chosen answer to your question as correct by clicking the checkmark next to it. Please do so; it helps motivate users to leave thorough answers and will help you get accurate answers to future questions.

Answer (score 10):

Off the top of my head:

> Why You Might Want To Leave Now
>
> Instead Of What You Wanted to Hear About, I Am Going To Talk About
>
> All The Things I'm Going To Try To Tell You If You'll Just Be Quiet
>
> The Stuff Standing Between You And Lunch
>
> I'm Going To Talk About The Following Because I Have The Remote
>
> A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away...
>
> Table of Contents, If You're Lucky

**EDIT** I got some more:

> I Swear This Won't Be A Boring As It Looks
>
> A Moose Bit My Sister
>
> "Now is the table of our discontent."
>
> Shut Up And Pay Attention

Comment: +1 for the Lunch line.  Oh, and I love the Remote bit too.  Quite funny.

Comment: I'd like it better as "... summary of our discontent" :-)

Answer (score 6):

I like this advice that I heard long ago:

1. Tell 'em what you're gonna' tell 'em.
2. Tell 'em.
3. Tell 'em what you told 'em.

Adjourn.

**EDIT** moved from a comment and added to this answer at the suggestion of @Neil Fein:

It's a professional presentation, you're a professional, so act like one. The best opening, imo, is "what I'm going to talk about." Anything else looks like you're apologizing for stealing their valuable time; if that were true, they wouldn't be in the audience. If you try for humor, it had better be sure-fire and guaranteed to bring a laugh, otherwise you will look as foolish, inept, and unprofessional as every other presenter who ever tried the exact same thing. Just imo.

Answer (score 3):

At the start of your presentation, show

> This is going to be legen - [wait for
>   it, wait for it ...](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wait%20for%20it)

and at the end, instead of **"THE END"**, put

> **DARY!**

Answer (score 3):

You could go old "school" and stick with "Objectives".

Answer (score 1):

Today's menu. Obstacle course. Things to come. Bad ideas. The sheet of music. (The last one would support a snarky intro, "just so we're all on the same sheet of..."

Also, consider not having a TOC. Just jump right in. If you want a header slide to your deck, pull out three to five key concepts and just show those.

The art of presentations now is leaning toward very bare, stripped down slides that support your talk, but do not detail it. Hard to describe, but when you see it done well, you know it.

Comment: Today's Menu is excellent, I'll use that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider removing the ToC page. I never use them any more, and nobody misses them.

Answer (score 1):

**Menu**

- egg and bacon
- egg sausage and bacon
- egg and spam
- egg bacon and spam
- egg bacon sausage and spam
- spam bacon sausage and spam
- spam egg spam spam bacon and spam
- spam sausage spam spam bacon spam tomato and spam
- Lobster Thermidor a Crevette with a mornay sauce served in a Provencale manner with shallots and aubergines garnished with truffle pate, brandy and with a fried egg on top and spam
- Conclusion

Answer (score 0):

1) The next 30 minutes ....
(or whatever is the duration of your presentation)

2) This discussion is about ...

Answer (score 0):

I use "Agenda" as the second slide in my presentations. First is the session title with my name, title, etc.

I don't read the agenda, and the name is self-explanatory. Just mention this is what will be covered and I talk about housekeeping, but this works well.

I have also at times used this same slide multiple times in the presentation at the beginning of each section, highlighting the area that is being covered.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the context of your presentation, but here are some quick, general suggestions:

1. The Lowdown
2. The Down n' Dirty
3. The Nitty Gritty
4. The Play by Play
5. The Deets